# How can I confirm which process is connect to remote port?

Tags: linux, networking, tcp, netstat, ss

My loacl server IP is 192.168.122.100, and remote server IP is 192.168.122.50. I need to kill all processes which connect to 192.168.122.50:56666. By executing `ss` comand, I found there are three TCP connections has been established. But I don't konw which process are  using these sockets. How can I find out the PID of these socket?
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `lsof` command. Usage:
`sudo lsof -ni tcp | grep <port>`
And the 2nd column is PID.

Answer (score 0):

This is for modern Linux'es:

```bsh
kill $(sudo netstat -n -eep | awk '/IP_ADDRESS:PORT.*ESTABLISHED/{print $9}' | awk -F / '{print $1}')
```